# Python Keras Input 0 of layer batch_normalization is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using CIFAR-10 Dataset to train some MLP models. I want to try data augmentation as the code block below.

```
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 32
epoch = 50

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
# convert from integers to floats
train_images = train_images.astype('float32')
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')
# normalize to range 0-1
train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

train_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes=10)
test_labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(test_labels, num_classes=10)

augment = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True)
it_train = augment.flow(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=batch_size)
```

And this is the model I use, you can see below.

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(units=1000, activation=activation, input_dim=3072))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=300, activation=activation))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=100, activation=activation))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
```

This is the line I train the model.

```
history = model.fit(it_train, steps_per_epoch=len(train_images), epochs=epoch, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

However, I get this error. CIFAR10 dataset is 32x32x3 and contains 10 labels.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer batch_normalization is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=2, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, None, 1000)
```

What can I do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input shape of CIRFAR is (`32, 32, 3`) but your model's input isn't taking that shape. You can try as follows for your model input.

```
model = keras.Sequential()

# Before 1st dense layer adding a Flatten layer that will flat the 
# coming tensor of shape (32, 32, 3).
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1000, activation=activation))

model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
...
```